# Numpy speed up nested loop with fancy indexing

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

i currently implemented an algorithm which calculates a quality assesment of disparity maps based on total variation.

I'm relatively new to python, but already read numerous threads on speed up numpy code. Views vs Fancy indexing, tried using Cython, Vectorization of nested loops etc. I achieved a bit of speed up's but altogether, i ended more and more in messy code without achieving a proper speed up.

I wonder if someone can give me a hint if there is a clean and easy way to speed up this 2d loop.

TV is a 2D array with ~ 15k x 15k elements
footprint_ix and _iy are 2 lists of arrays which contain the index offset to the neighbor pixels if pixel x,y in a ringshaped manner. With m = 1 the 8 neighborpixels are selected, m = 2 the next 16, and so on

The algorithm sums up the neighbor pixels of x,y and increases m when a threshold TAU is not exceeded.

The best solution i come up with, so far uses row-wise multiprocessing.

```
# create footprints
footprint_ix = []
footprint_iy = []
for m in range(1, m_classes):    
    fp = np.ones((2 * m + 1, 2 * m + 1), dtype = int)
    fp [ 1 : -1, 1 : -1] = 0
    i, j = np.nonzero(fp)
    i = i - m
    j = j - m

    footprint_ix.append(i)
    footprint_iy.append(j)


m_classes = 21
for x in xrange( 0, rows):
    for y in xrange ( 0, cols):   
        if disp[x,y] == np.inf: 
            continue
        else:
            tv_m = 0

            for m_i in range (0, m_classes-1):
                m = m_i + 1
                try:
                    tv_m += np.sum( tv[footprint_ix[m_i] + x, footprint_iy[m_i] + y] )  / (8 * m)                   
                except IndexError:
                    tv_m = np.inf

                if tv_m >= TAU:
                    tv_classes[x,y] = m
                    break

                if m == m_classes - 1:
                    tv_classes[x,y] = m
```

Comment: "uses row-wise multiprocessing" - huh?  Your code doesn't use multiprocessing.  Also, can you post a full executable script that we can run which includes example or random input data?

Comment: Why are you testing for `IndexError`?  If you can index in a way that avoids that, you might be able change the the `m_i` loop into a pure numpy expression.  I usually solve problems like this by removing loops from the inside out.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, i was looking for a hint like this